# DataGrid style changes in different computers

Tags: wpf, styles, wpfdatagrid

I have a problem with a dataGrid style that changes between different computers.
I have scenario where : One row is selected , we change the selection to a different row (Change is done from the code) , and it seem like the previous row is also still selected (Even though when debugging we can see it is not realy selected, only presented as it is selected).
This happens only in one computer, in a different computer the previous row is not marked as selected , but there is a different mark (i'm not sure it is related )  around the cell

I suspect there is some property the previous row is marking as true , and it's style is similar to the selection style. Any Idea what this property might be?
And Why does it presented differently in different computers?

Or if you have any other idea what might be the problem to the multi selection view (When only one row is actually selected).

(I didn't manage to add an Image to make it more clear , my reputation is not high enough yet )

Thanks,
Dana.

Answer (score 0):

Without any other information such as code, OS all I can do is guess.
DataGrid has a private variable called _selectionAnchor that is responsible for highlighting the row you clicked. I have a similar issue trying to validate the datagrid row selection and I tracked down to this little friend. That might be what is causing your problem.